# Converting a linkedlist to binary tree

Tags: java, data-structures, tree, linked-list, binary-tree

I've a linked list that has two links - `next` and `another` assume. Initially, all `another` hold `null`. Now, I'm trying to convert this to a binary tree with `next` holding the `liftChild` and `another` holding `rightChild`. However, I want to do this in O(n) and in constant space. I've tried a lot. Below is my code. I'm verifying the result by level-order traversing the resulting tree. Currently, I know what's the mistake but don't know how to solve it. The mistake here is that inside the `while` loop, I'm changing the links of the `node` properly, but this means I cannot do `node = node.next` at the end because `node`'s `next` is already pointing somewhere ahead in the list. So, I don't know how to traverse every node. Any hint, help is appreciated. Not hw, not interview question or anything. Just trying to learn data structures. So, this tree and ll stuff!

```
public class LlToBt {

  public SpecialNode llToBt(SpecialNode node) {
    SpecialNode temp = node;
    SpecialNode returnNode = node;

    if(node == null)
      return null;
    if(node.next == null)
      return node;

    node = returnNode;
    while(node != null) {
      SpecialNode currentNode = node;

      temp = temp.next;
      if(temp == null) {
        //node.next = null;
        //node.another = null;
        return returnNode;
      }
      node.next = temp;

      temp = temp.next;
      if(temp == null) {
        //node.next = null;
        //node.another = null;
        return returnNode;
      }
      node.another = temp;

      node = currentNode.next;

    }

    return returnNode;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are changing the link that you will want to traverse before you traverse it, then you need to store off in a different variable the result of the traversal *before* you change the link. Then after the change, you can traverse using your temporary copy.